# Rendering Terms and Conditions on CMS Page?

Tags: magento2, frontend

I'd like to render my Terms and Conditions on a CMS page, and it'd be best if these were pulled from the same Terms and Conditions as configured in Stores -> Terms and Conditions, so that they stay synchronized with each other. Any tips on how to achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Unfortunately not. Still hoping someone randomly swoops in and drops some wisdom on us.

Comment: Check this, I got an answer https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/220500/show-terms-and-conditions-on-static-page