# Show terms and conditions on static page

Tags: magento2, module, static-content, terms-and-conditions

Is there a way to show the terms and conditions on a page via `.phtml`?
I have made a page via a module and now want to show the terms and conditions on that page.

Comment: Have you created terms and condition page via Content > Page and you want to display content of CMS page to your .phtml file?

Comment: Have you needed terms & condition content on your custom page right?

Comment: @HitarthPattani  Yes, I have created terms and conditions. Also they are visible via the check out. Furthermore, I have created a front end page on which I want to show the terms and conditions via a .phtml file which I included within the .xml file of the page I created (termsconditions_index_index.xml)

Comment: @Abdul Yes indeed, I want the terms and conditions to show on my custom page.

Comment: add your terms and condition in a static block and then add your static block to the phtml file, you can refer [this answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/156412/20064)

Comment: @Piyush That's not the way I want it too. When a client changes the terms and conditions in the backend, of course the terms and conditions on the page I created have to be changed too. Adding them in a static block forces me to change it every time the terms and conditions change

Comment: have you created any block for terms & condition?

Comment: Not per se. But of course I could do that.

Comment: @bramulous then you need to store those terms and condition in a database table and then get it in your phtml file

Comment: @Piyush Abdul's answer was what I was looking for. But thanks for your effort!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Step:1** 
First add below code in your `termsconditions_index_index.xml` file.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\CheckoutAgreements\Block\Agreements" name="terms_condition"  template="test/test.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

**Step:2** Add below code in your .phtm file

```
<?php
/**
 * @var $block \Magento\CheckoutAgreements\Block\Agreements
 */
?>
<?php if (!$block->getAgreements()) {
    return;
} ?>
<ol class="agreements items">
<?php foreach ($block->getAgreements() as $agreement): ?>
    <li class="item">
        <?php if ($agreement->getIsHtml()):?>
            <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $agreement->getContent() ?>
        <?php else:?>
            <?php echo nl2br($block->escapeHtml($agreement->getContent())) ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </li>
<?php endforeach ?>
</ol>
```

**Note:** Please add your .phtml file path in `termsconditions_index_index.xml`

I have putted currently `template="test/test.phtml"`

After run below command:

```
php setup:di:compile
```

Comment: Wow you're amazing dude! I don't doubt that more people will need this in the future! Thanks man!

Comment: @bramulous Welcome :D

Comment: @Abdul, in which path the file termsconditions_index_index.xml should be?

Comment: @jafarpinjar termsconditions_index_index is a custom module file 

for eg. app/code/AR/Termsconditions/view/frontend/layout/termsconditions_index_index.xml

Comment: @Abdul, can you please share your module please?