# Why does getAgreements() return nothing?

Tags: magento2, module, magento2.2.3, terms-and-conditions

I've made a custom module, with the ability to print the terms and conditions on a static page. I've achieved this by posting a question on Stack, which answer worked for me:
[Show terms and conditions on static page](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/220500/show-terms-and-conditions-on-static-page)

(I've followed to above exactly)

Now, I've created the module with the intention to be reused in other instances of Magento 2(.2.3). So, I've installed the module on a clean installation of Magento 2:

- Enabled developer mode
- Created corresponding vendor folder
- Uploaded the module to the vendor folder
- ran `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`
- ran `php bin/magento setup:di:compile`
- created terms and conditions
- enabled the function in the backend (I created a Helper for this)
- ran `php bin/magento cache:flush`
- Browsed to *http://www.mywebshop.com/termsconditions*

The `/termsconditions` url loads correctly, so this means the module is working. But somehow, the code which gets the agreement content, returns *empty*?

This all may sound like a stupid question, but as far as I know, there shouldn't be going something wrong.

var_dump of `$block->getAgreements()` returns

```
array (size=0)
  empty
```

Whilst I have created terms and conditions via the admin menu and which show up correctly.

Also the terms and conditions show up in the DB.

Someone who knows what I might have forgotten or what is going wrong?

The code in `.phtml`

```
<?php
/**
 * @var $block \Magento\CheckoutAgreements\Block\Agreements
 */
?>

<ol class="agreements items">
    <?php var_dump($block->getAgreements()) ?>
    <?php foreach ($block->getAgreements() as $agreement): ?>
        <li class="item">
            <?php if ($agreement->getIsHtml()):?>
                <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $agreement->getContent() ?>
            <?php else:?>
                <?php echo nl2br($block->escapeHtml($agreement->getContent())) ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach ?>
</ol>
```

Layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <title>Terms and Conditions</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="page.main.title" remove="true" />
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\CheckoutAgreements\Block\Agreements" name="terms_conditions"  template="Vendor_TCRender::terms.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>

    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: add your layout file too.

Comment: I've added the layout file

Comment: enabled the function in the backend (I created a Helper for this) means?

Comment: I've have made a tab under `Stores -> Configuration`, with a Yes/No selector which enables me to disable or enable the `/termsconditions` page. When turned off, `/termsconditions` will redirect to `/404`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Enable Terms and Conditions option is "No" in your webshop. make sure that it is enabled from `Store > Configuration > Checkout > Checkout Options > Enable Terms and Conditions`

After saving configuration clear the cache `php bin/magento c:f`

Comment: Wow. The moment you think you finally get a finger around Magento, I discover I still have a lot to learn. Thank you man, was too focused on the code to forget such a simple setting...

Comment: Glad that it helps you :)