# Magento2 terms and condition in popup with cms block not working

Tags: magento2

I have Magento 2.2.3 and activated terms and conditions. And I added

```
{{block class="Magento\\Cms\\Block\\Block" area='frontend' block_id="agb"}} {{block class="Magento\\Cms\\Block\\Block" block_id="agb"}}
```

but in popup no text is shown, only above code is shown. Anyone an idea what is wrong? I use same snippet in other shop and it is working

Thanks!
Martin
[image]

Comment: Have you added static block in phtml file or CMS page ?

Comment: yes - and it is active

Answer (score 0):

The agreements are rendered via knockout js, therefore you cannot add a cms block to their content, you could go and extend the agreements module to process the data before sending it to the frontend via knockout, but i would just turn things around.

Don't include a cms block inside the agreements, but include the agreements in your cms page as follows:

use the Layout/design update xml field for the cms page with something like the following:

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
    <block class="Magento\CheckoutAgreements\Block\Agreements" name="agb.agreement" template="Vendor_Module::html/agreements/agb.phtml" after="-" />
</referenceContainer>
```

and the corresponding template to insert exactly the one agreement you want:

```
<?php
/**
 * @var $block \Magento\CheckoutAgreements\Block\Agreements
 */

/**
 * Define agreement for display
 *
 * Copy this template if you wish to insert an agreements static content somewhere
 *
 * @var $display_agreement string - Agreement id or name
 */
$display_agreement = 'AGB';

/**
 * Process
 */
$was_found = false;
foreach ($block->getAgreements() as $agreement) {

    // Found requested agreement
    if ($agreement->getId() == $display_agreement || $agreement->getName() == $display_agreement) {
        $was_found = true;
        print '<div class="agreement_content">';
        if ($agreement->getIsHtml()) {
            /* @escapeNotVerified */
            print $agreement->getContent();
        } else {
            print nl2br($block->escapeHtml($agreement->getContent()));
        }
        print '</div>';
    }
}

if (!$was_found) {
    throw new Exception('Agreement display failed, could not find: ' + $display_agreement);
}
```

You can find some more info on the agreements block here: [Why does getAgreements() return nothing?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/221749/why-does-getagreements-return-nothing)

Answer (score 0):

agreement content is load from class Magento\CheckoutAgreements\Model\AgreementsConfigProvider protected function getAgreementsConfig()

```
'content' => $agreement->getIsHtml()
                ? $agreement->getContent()
                : nl2br($this->escaper->escapeHtml($agreement->getContent()))
```

could override using [preference](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/build/di-xml-file.html#override-a-method-using-preference-nodes)

use below function to get cms block content

```
/** @var \Magento\Framework\View\LayoutInterface  */
protected $_layout;

public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\View\LayoutInterface $layout)
{
    $this->_layout = $layout;
}

public function getContent()
{
    $cmsBlockId = 1; // id of cms block to use

    return $this->_layout->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId($cmsBlockId)->toHtml();
}
```

Comment: Can you specify which files to edit and where to put them to avoid core overrides?