# Terms and conditions from Static block magento2

Tags: magento2, checkout, cms-block, terms-and-conditions

I need to show Terms and condition text before place order button of each payment method.

Which file i need to override to show content from static block. As i checked terms and conditions text comes from html and not from phtml file.

So is it possibile to display content from the cms static block?

Please anyone help on this. Thanks

Comment: you try this module https://github.com/trubnikovr/magento2_CheckoutAgreement, works on M2.3

Comment: check my answer here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/224725/magento2-terms-and-condition-in-popup-with-cms-block-not-working/341562#341562

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you want to show a formatted content in the terms and conditions section in the checkout page.

By default, it is not possible to call the content in this block from a CMS block.

I have a workaround for it.

1. Create a temporary static block and write your HTML content in it. Check the preview of HTML. Once finalized, go to step 2.
2. Go to **Stores** >> **Settings (Terms and Conditions)** and edit existing or create a new condition with the following settings:

   -- **Status:** Enabled

   -- **Show Content as:** HTML

   Now, copy the HTML content from the static block which you created in **step #1** and paste its **Content** in the content section of this condition. Save the condition.
3. Now go to **Stores** >> **Configuration** >> **Sales (Checkout)** section and under **Checkout Options**, change the value of Enable Terms and Conditions to Yes. Save Config.

That's all.

Comment: hi @Mohit, this i will try but in future to change content again it can't be changed from static block instead we need to change from terms and conditions only. is there any way to load static block content in that area like we call in other phtml files.

Comment: Programmatically it could be possible, but I haven't tried it yet.

Comment: If it is loading from phtml file, then we can call it, but it loads from html

Comment: Yes, you are right. The checkout page uses knockout JS to render most of the content.

Comment: okay, let me check with your approach. thanks

Comment: hi mohit, here there is a checkbox this is a mandatory, can we remove it?

Comment: Then how do you want the customer to accept the terms and conditions?

Comment: If you want the checkbox to be autochecked and hidden, you can write a simple javascript code to check the checkbox on page load and then hide it.

Comment: That's fine, but it comes with pop up instead a text at that place. better approach is to load phtml there? is that possible?

Comment: @jafarpinjar, I tried but could not find an easy way to remove pop up and show textarea.

Comment: Can you please upvote if the solution (workaround) worked for you, since the pop up thing was not the part of initial question.

Comment: hi mohit, I have enabled Terms and conditions but not able to place order. Always getting Please agree to all the terms and conditions before placing the order for any payment methods

Comment: hi @Mohit, can you please update me the fix if could find it

Comment: I have tried it in different Magento 2 environments with different payment methods. At my side, I could not find any error. I am able to place order.

Comment: In my case what might be the issue? even no error in log .

Comment: Have you checked apache error logs?

Comment: Yes, there also no errors found, Its a magento 2 bug i guess, my version is 2.2.4

Comment: Can you update your findings in the question update?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86911/discussion-between-jafar-pinjar-and-mohit-kumar-arora).