# Pull in Terms and Conditions from Static Block

Tags: checkout, cms-block, magento2.3.5, terms-and-conditions

On Terms and Conditions we try to pull in a static block

```
{{block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" block_id="terms_and_conditions"}}

{{block id='terms_and_conditions'}}
```

[image: Screen]

Both variants are displayed as code and the static block content is not resolved.

Why is this?

*edit* There is this module: https://github.com/UnimixPro/magento2_CheckoutAgreement

I believe it worked out of the box in earlier Magento versions.

Comment: you try this [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/252641/terms-and-conditions-from-static-block-magento2) **click**

Comment: This seems to copy the terms, not including them to avoid duplicating the legal terms in the admin panel. I believe this was working in older Magento versions.

Comment: The module you linked does nothing. Is just a stub. As you can clearly see here https://github.com/UnimixPro/magento2_CheckoutAgreement/blob/master/Nikov/CheckoutAgreement/Plugin/Frontend/Magento/CheckoutAgreements/Model/Agreement.php they expect to write your own code

Comment: I believe it does something here         return $this->_filterProvider->getPageFilter()->filter($result);